# microsoft bot framework to open a url without user intervention

Tags: botframework, cortana, cortana-skills-kit

There are hero card or thumbnail card examples where you can render a button to open a URL like below

```
 msg.attachments([ 
        new builder.ThumbnailCard(session)
        .title('Brian Mathew')
        .subtitle('CIO, Logistics')
        .text('San Francisco Bay Area - 30 Mutual Connections')
        .images([
            builder.CardImage.create(session, 'https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C5103AQHt4Rp2MT0quA/profile-displayphoto-shrink_800_800/0?e=1527022800&v=alpha&t=gQbe7EXQX1S3wYr8QpCjXqeWyKzM0vQWE0M51WGL8n4')
        ])
        .buttons([
            builder.CardAction.openUrl(session, 'https://google.com', 'More Details')
        ])
```

However, in my use case, I do not want to show any button for an explicit call and simply let user take to the url. Take it like saying Open google.com. I could not find a way to do that plz advise

Comment: I don't think it's possible on any channel, certainly not on consumer ones. It has end user security implications of course. If you build your own channel (chat, webchat, etc.) well, you just have to invent a common convention between your bot and your custom channel

Comment: For obvious security reasons, this is not possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said by @JasonSowers, for obvious security reasons, this is not possible.

Or it would be the spammest feature ever!